# Postgresql and JDBC checking for TYPE ENUM in metadata

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to get a database metadata and determine the table I have created is present or not. I am able to get the table which i have created, but I am facing Issue with getting TYPE ENUM in the metadata. You can find the JDBC code I have, what should I do to get the TYPE ENUM?

The bwlow code print the tables i have created perfectly fine, but I cannot get the ENUM TYPE which I created. Should I add any additional types like `ENUM`?

```
void printDBTables(@NonNull final Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    final DatabaseMetaData dbMetadata = connection.getMetaData();
    final String[] types = {"TABLE"};
    final ResultSet rs = dbMetadata.getTables(null, null, null, types);
    while (rs.next()) {
        log.info("Found Table with name: {}", rs.getString(3));
    }
```

I am little new to java and any help here is appreciated. Below is the sample query I am using `CREATE TYPE TESTQ AS ENUM ('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE');`

Answer (score 1):

Since `enum` types are not standard SQL, it cannot be expected that JDBC makes any provisions for them.

You'll have to query the PostgreSQL metadata:

```
SELECT t.typname, e.enumlabel
FROM pg_type AS t
   JOIN pg_enum AS e ON t.oid = e.enumtypid
WHERE t.typname = 'testq'
ORDER BY e.enumsortorder;

 typname | enumlabel 
---------+-----------
 testq   | ONE
 testq   | TWO
 testq   | THREE
(3 rows)
```